# Use the right color scale for data skewed to right

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, data-visualization

I have data whose domain is [0, 100] but they are not uniform, they are very skewed to the right, that is, most of them have a value between 80 and 100.

I want to make visualizations with this data and use the color to distinguish them (ex: heatmap, map, ...).

What is the right color scale to use?

I tried the linear scale, the power scale and the quantile scales. 
The best one seems like the quantile scales but there are still problems:

1. I would like to better distinguish the colors of the last values (values to the right), they all seem black, is it possible?
2. in this example I used a gray scale, and if instead I wanted to use the *Viridis* or *Magma* scale?

[image]

Here is my code.

```js
function sortNumber(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

var data = [90, 95, 50, 1, 99, 89.1, 87, 94, 95, 99, 99.5, 94.3, 96, 97, 85, 74, 66, 92, 68, 91, 93, 87, 79, 86, 89, 93.5, 97, 98];
data.sort(sortNumber); // [1, 50, 66, 68, 74, 79, 85, 86, 87, 87, 89, 89.1, 90, 91, 92, 93, 93.5, 94, 94.3, 95, 95, 96, 97, 97, 98, 99, 99, 99.5]
console.log(data);

var colMin = '#ffffff';
var colMax = '#000000';

// LINEAR SCALE
var scaleLinear = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([colMin, colMax]);

var div = d3.select("#lin").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "dive")
  .style("background-color", d => scaleLinear(d));


// POWER SCALE
var scalePow = d3.scalePow()
  .exponent(10)
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([colMin, colMax]);

var div = d3.select("#pow").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "dive")
  .style("background-color", d => scalePow(d));


// QUANTILE SCALE (using https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/color-blend/#:::hex to find intermediate colors)
var scaleQuantile = d3.scaleQuantile()
  .domain(data)
  .range([colMin, "#E8E8E8", "#D1D1D1", "#B9B9B9", "#A2A2A2", "#8B8B8B", "#747474", "#5D5D5D", "#464646", "#2E2E2E", "#171717", colMax]);

var div = d3.select("#qua").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "dive")
  .style("background-color", d => scaleQuantile(d));
```

```css
.dive {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 0.5px black solid;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>color scheme</title>
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <script src="//d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v0.3.min.js"></script> <!-- for scale color -->
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script> <!-- for scale color -->

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="lin">
    <p>Scale linear</p>
   </div><br>

   <div id="pow">
    <p>Scale power</p>
   </div><br>

   <div id="qua">
    <p>Scale quantile</p>
   </div>

   <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Quantile is probably your best bet. [Updated](https://plnkr.co/edit/f78m5Ub4CelzZAAeZhYv?p=preview) I made a small update which quantizes a scale on the quantile, looks very similar.

Comment: It's funny (and annoying) that this question has 24 views and two answers, but **nobody** upvoted it. If this is not a question *"showing research effort, useful and clear"*, I don't know what it is. +1.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> What is the right color scale to use?

There's not a right color scale. All depends what you want to show, hide, sell, yours customers, clients, users, publics.-

On the other hand you have D3 as a tool to show whats you need.-

You could use a custom scale, like so:

```
  // --------------------- Custom  SCALE
var custom = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,       50,       90,        95,       100])
  .range(['#edfc1b','#ec6f3b','#bc2e67','#7c0093', '#0b0074']);

var div = d3.select("#custom").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "dive")
  .style("background-color", d => custom(d));
```

Which gives you this:

[image]

There's others scales.

[image]

I've fork your Plunker to extend it: [**HERE**](https://plnkr.co/edit/7M92tKEyXfUGOZIPYhxH?p=preview)

I think you're missing an important point: you're dropping information.
The right way to show this is leaving empty space for lack of data, such as any color-scale will work. Like so:

[image]

From you image

[image]

On "Scale Quantile" and "Scale Power", "value 1" has same color as "value 50". Even when you label each box with his value, it's too difficult noticed.-

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to better distinguish the colors of the last values
>   (values to the right), they all seem black, is it possible?

As Klaujesi suggested, making your own color scale is probably your best bet. I would refer to Klaujesi's answer for coding guidance on creating your own color scheme.

As you've identified, you have a lot of data points of similar value, which the scales you've been experimenting with have reflected. Personally, I would consider still letting your scale reflect that fact, rather than trying too hard to hide it with a more attractive scale. I would recommend thinking about what your data means, and creating a scale to reflect that. For instance, maybe all data points in the 90 to 100 range should have a more similar color than the data points in the 80 to 100 range. Or maybe you really should let all the colors look the same because it's significant that all the data is the same.

> in this example I used a gray scale, and if instead I wanted to use
>   the Viridis or Magma scale?

Thanks to your work in putting together a good example, adding one of these color schemes shouldn't be too difficult. Here's an example with a linear scale.

Add to the bottom of script.js:

```
// VIRIDIS
var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([0, 1]);

var div = d3.select("#vir").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "dive")
  .style("background-color", d => d3.interpolateViridis(colorScale(d)));
```

Add within your `<body>` of `index.html`:

```
<div id="vir">
    <p>Viridis colors</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your data is skewed to the right, this is my suggestion:

Use a [sequential scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#sequential-scales), in this example with `interpolateViridis`:

```
var scale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis);
```

And simply use the **index** of the datum with the interpolator:

```
.style("background-color", function(_, i) {
    return scale(i / (data.length - 1))
});
```

Or, as you're using the viridis *reversed*:

```
.style("background-color", function(_, i) {
    return scale(1 - (i / (data.length - 1)))
});
```

The reasoning is that, with a sequential scale, only the *index* of the datum in the data array matters, but not the datum itself. Because of that, be sure that the data array is sorted.

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [90, 95, 50, 1, 99, 89.1, 87, 94, 95, 99, 99.5, 94.3, 96, 97, 85, 74, 66, 92, 68, 91, 93, 87, 79, 86, 89, 93.5, 97, 98];
data.sort();
var scale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateViridis);
var div = d3.select("#myDiv").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "div")
  .style("background-color", function(_, i) {
    return scale(1 - (i / (data.length - 1)))
  });
  
var divValue = d3.select("#myDivValue").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "div2")
  .html(Number)
```

```css
.div {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 0.5px black solid;
}

.div2 {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 0.5px white solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>Sequential scale with Viridis</p>
</div>
<div id="myDivValue"></div>
```

Same code, using `interpolateMagma`:

```js
var data = [90, 95, 50, 1, 99, 89.1, 87, 94, 95, 99, 99.5, 94.3, 96, 97, 85, 74, 66, 92, 68, 91, 93, 87, 79, 86, 89, 93.5, 97, 98];
data.sort();
var scale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateMagma);
var div = d3.select("#myDiv").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "div")
  .style("background-color", function(_, i) {
    return scale(1 - (i / (data.length - 1)))
  });
var divValue = d3.select("#myDivValue").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "div2")
  .html(Number);
```

```css
.div {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 0.5px black solid;
}

.div2 {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 0.5px white solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>Sequential scale with Magma</p>
</div>
<div id="myDivValue"></div>
```

PS: I'm using D3 v5 here. If you're using v4 you may need to reference the necessary microlibraries.

Comment: Hi Gerardo, I have a similar problem and I want to use sequential scale. Can you better explain the reason for `scale(1 - (i / (data.length - 1)))`? Why did not you just use `scale(i)`?